# jQuery :last selector odd behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The `:last` selector is, in some cases, returning more than one element. [Here there is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/F4CrV/) to try it because its hard to believe!

Code one fails:

```
alert($(".child").find("span:last").length); // -> alerts 3
```

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

> Description: Selects the last matched element.
>
> Note that :last selects a single element by filtering the current
>   jQuery collection and matching the last element within it.

Am I missing something or this is a bug?

Comment: if you want to find the last of them, use $(".child").last("span")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `.find()` with `:first` and `:last`, it searches for the first and last element *relatively to each ancestor element* that was found using `$('.child')`.

Since you have three `.child` elements, you have three elements in which to search for `span`s. Since each `.child` has exactly one `span`, `:last` turns up each one of those three in the context of `.find()`. Then `.find()` collects them all together, and so you have three `span` elements as a result.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, I think what you need is:

```
alert( $(".child:last").find("span:last").length );
```

Because otherwise with only "child" as selection you will always enter the first.

Answer (score 0):

Dissecting your test, we have:

```
var matches = [];
$('.child').each(function(){
    //get collection of all spans in the element
    var collection = $('span',this);

    //NOTE: There is only 1 span in collection at this point

    //get last element
    var match = collection.last();
    matches.push(match);
});
alert(matches.length); //which is obviously 3
```